# Need to execute winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="192.168.4.231"}' command from PowerShell script from remote

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I am firing following script from remote machine to add the executer IP (192.168.4.231) in trusted list. but the below script is getting fired but not I am not getting desired results.

Please let me know is there any wrong way I am executing below script.

```
$servers = @("192.168.4.236")
foreach($server in $servers) {
    $username = 'administrator'
    $password = '*******'
    $pw   = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
    $cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $pw)
    $s = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred
    Enter-PSSession $s
    Invoke-Command -Session $s -Scriptblock {
        Invoke-Expression 'winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="192.168.4.231"}''
    }
    Write-Host "Completed"
    Remove-PSSession $s
}
```

Comment: Why do yiu use `enter-pssession` ? This command can not be used in a script and it is also unnecessary. You will connect to the remote machine with the session parameter from the command `invoke-command`

Comment: The quoting of the expression inside the scriptblock is incorrect too, and you [shouldn't be using `Invoke-Expression`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/) in the first place. Besides "not getting the desired results" is not a valid problem description. What results did you expect? And what did you actually get?

Comment: the expected result should be add the said ip in trustedhost list

Comment: Do you get any error message? What happens when you execute the winrm command on the remote machine exactly as it is `Invoke-Expression 'winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="192.168.4.231"}'` ?

Comment: Could you try and add one backtick before the double quotes `Invoke-Expression "winrm set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts=``"192.168.4.231``"}"` . I have problems with formating in the comment box. Only ONE backtick!

Comment: for me, adding single quotes got it to work, so ``winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="192.168.4.231"}'``. Also had to begin with``winrm quickconfig`` to enable WinRM on my machine.